# Ractive partial external file

Tags: partials, ractivejs

I have a pretty complicated web page i am trying to build with Ractive,
It contains many partial templates.
I am trying to load a partial from a separate file just to keep my code clean.

Example:

```
<script id='content' type='text/ractive'>
 Hello!
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/efrsmqhd/

How can i put 'content' into a separate file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Ractive tries to find a partial - let's say `{{>foo}}` - it first looks for `ractive.partials.foo`. Then it looks for `ractive.partials[valueOfFoo]` - so if `ractive.get('foo') === 'bar'`, it will look for `ractive.partials.bar`.

Only when those have failed will it look for `<script id='foo'>`. So you can pass in your partials explicitly, like so:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '{{>foo}}',
  partials: {
    foo: '<p>this is a <strong>foo</strong> partial</p>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

The prototype of `ractive.partials` is `Ractive.partials`, so if you have several Ractive instances on the page, they can share partials like so:

```js
Ractive.partials.foo = '<p>this is a <strong>foo</strong> partial</p>';

var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '{{>foo}}'
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

So keeping your partials in separate files is as straightforward as loading them via AJAX and passing them in when you call `new Ractive()`. Of course, if you have lots of separate files, that becomes trickier, because you have to load them all *before* you can call `new Ractive()`. There are a number of ways to coordinate all that asynchronous activity, but the easiest way is to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) - here's an example that uses the [window.fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch):

```js
var ractive, partials = {}, promises;

promises = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ].map( function ( name ) {
  return fetch( 'templates/' + name + '.html' ).then( function ( response ) {
    return response.text().then(function(text) {
      partials[ name ] = text;
    });
  });
});

Promise.all( promises ).then( function () {
  ractive = new Ractive({
    el: 'body',
    template: '#template',
    partials: partials
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rich - this is exactly what I've been looking for. Not seen fetch before. However, I wasn't receiving the fetched html body. Instead, I received some weird looking nested object* containing the html on a key called `[[PromisesValue]]`. So I refactored things slightly.

This returns the response.text, and then puts it onto partials. I now have all my templates (about 30 so far) in separate files :D

```
 promises = [  'foo' , 'bar' ,'baz' ].map( function ( name ) {
      return fetch( 'templates/' + name + '.html' ).then( function ( response ) {
         return response.text()
      }).then(function(body) {
        partials[name] = body;
      });
    });


    Promise.all( promises ).then( function () { ...
```

*it looked weird in Chromes debugger. My next job is to grok ractive components :)

Comment: ```
partials:
partialTemplate: {"html code"}
```

How do I display in the view?
`{{>partialTemplate}}` 

this is not working for me